# htaccess redirect loop

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am having issue in the last line of the below code which is causing the redirect loop (at least that's what i think so)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jgel/
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^172\.172\.121\.142
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !maintainance\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !resources/(.*)$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ maintenance.php [R=307,L]
```

I have tried this and this too doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^172\.172\.121\.142
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !maintainance\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !resources/(.*)$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /jgel/maintenance.php [R=307,L]
```

Comment: Have you tried with `R=302`?

Comment: Can you provide the response header that you're getting from the server, and maybe the contents of a `RewriteLogFile` with `RewriteLogLevel 9` set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jgel/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !maintainance\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ maintainance.php [R=307,L]
```

This should do what you need ; you can add other two conditions if you want but this is minimum working example, I've tested on Apache 2.2.